# What are the mouse/keyboard sequences for cut-and-paste on Ubuntu VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, cut-and-paste

I have a *non-graphical* `Ubuntu` installed inside `VirtualBox` under `Windows`.
I've installed `VBoxGuestAdditions` (and enabled *bidirectional* `Drag'n'Drop` - for the hell of it).

However, none of the following will paste to the guest OS:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
- Pressing right-click and left-click simultaneously (this emulates a middle-click on my laptop's two keys touch-pad).

### What are the sequences for mouse/keyboard cut-and-paste in non-graphical Ubuntu under VirtualBox?

**Environment:**

- VirtualBox: 4.3.12 r93733
- VBoxGuest: 4.3.12
- Guest OS: Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP x86_64
- Host OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

After extensive research, seems this issue has no straightforward solution.
However, [forums.virtualbox.org](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=67357&sid=2a5236bebef9d59e399b52b643fb1d6a&p=318709#p318709) member [loukingjr](https://forums.virtualbox.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=30872) suggested this cleaver  workaround:

> I recommend installing ssh server, then connecting to the VM with the SSH client of your choice, e.g. PuTTY - this offers not only easy cut&paste, but also a resizable text console and other goodies. – Eugen Rieck